# Can inherited classes details be returned when called from a SOAP method returning the base class?

Tags: c#, web-services, logging, soap

I am wondering what is the best way of returning data to a client where the data is similar in some way. We have a requirement to allow clients to connect to our software via a SOAP method, and we will return all the 'events' which have happened to a particular object.

For example in an online store the events might be adding item to basket, placing order, paying for order. In this example our software would use the following class structure:

```
public class Event
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventTime { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class ProductEvent : Event
{
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
}

public class OrderEvent : Event
{
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
}
```

At the moment we can create xml files that might look like the following

```
<Events>
    <ProductEvent>
        <Id>0000-0000-0000-0000</Id>
        <EventTime>01-01/-0001T00:00:00</EventTime>
        <Username>User</Username>
        <Message>Added to basket</Message>
        <ProductId>00001</ProductId>
    </ProductEvent>
    <ProductEvent>
        <Id>0000-0000-0000-0000</Id>
        <EventTime>01-01/-0001T00:00:00</EventTime>
        <Username>User</Username>
        <Message>Added to basket</Message>
        <ProductId>00002</ProductId>
    </ProductEvent>
    <OrderEvent>
        <Id>0000-0000-0000-0000</Id>
        <EventTime>01-01/-0001T00:00:00</EventTime>
        <Username>User</Username>
        <Message>Added to basket</Message>
        <OrderId>000001</OrderId>
        <Products>
            <ProductId>00001</ProductId>
            <ProductId>00002</ProductId>
        </Products>
    </OrderEvent>
</Events>
```

Is it possible to return this type of data over SOAP from one method, or would there need to be separate methods for each event type?

I.e. can I return something similar to the above by calling a method with returned `IList<Event>` using SOAP?

Is there a better way to achieve event logging than this? The only way I could think of was to have just the `Event` class an contain all of the information in a Description property, which would make searching very difficult as you would have to search for a property written into text?

**EDIT**

Should have mentioned, when trying to return an `IList<Event>` where the contents may be derived from `Event` causes an error on the client:

`An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

Is there a way to do what I am attempting, or if not is there a better method or design pattern to follow.

Comment: Have you tried it? What happens when you return a List<Event> from your webservice?

Comment: @Mike sorry should have included this.

Comment: This should work when you use a collection class instead of an interface. Instead of `IList<T>` & `ICollection<T>`, use `List<T>`.